# 404 Not Found Errors -> Redirect

Tags: redirects, 404

Hi i have recently moved my forum from Mybb to Vanilla, so the index pages such as showthread.php now do not exist. This is a big problem for SEO, what do I do to redirect this to the home page?

Answer (score 3):

In your *.htaccess* file:-

```
redirect 301 /path/to/url http://www.domain.com/path/to/new/url
```

Note the first URL has no domain name, but the second one does.

Comment: Is there a way to just redirect all 404 errors though?

Comment: @Henry Hoggard You can -- using mod_rewrite, but what is the point? If I hit non-existing page I would like either to be redirected to a proper new location of the same page (as per @toomanyairmiles answer) or see an error page (preferably with some hints on what other pages may be interesting for me based on my URL). Why do I need to see your home page (or whatever) if I hit some random and invalid URL (e.g. `yoursite.com/bla-bla`)?

Comment: @HenryHoggard agree with LazyOne - design a 404 page which helps users - this isn't about search engines.

Comment: Once i have designed a 404 page how do i assign it?

Comment: @HenryHoggard in your htaccess 'ErrorDocument 404 path/to/404.php'